# Power jack connector and moisture problems

Tags: pcb-design, connector, humidity, power-connector

I have an inquiry about a design with a 3-pin jack connector, the PJ-065A. [Datasheet of this connector](https://www.mouser.es/datasheet/2/670/pj_065a-1778510.pdf)

[image: PJ-065A]

I want to use this power jack connector for a design.

I have selected this component because of its 3 terminals. My design comprises a Li-Ion battery, a circuitry to power (PCB with several components connected), and a charger for the battery. The battery and the PCB with the other components are enclosed in a box, and the charger is placed outside the box.

The battery is 2447-3036-20 Ansmann 14,8V 3500mAh [link](https://www.blubattery.com/home/li-ion-battery-packs/2447-3036-20-ansmann-batteria-ricaricabile-li-ion-14-8v-3500mah-type-4s1p-con-ptc-e-safety-board-certificata-un-38-3-e-iec-62133-2-2017.2.7.946.gp.10254.uw). The jack could be a 24V and max current would be 2A for this circuit. The charger I intend to use is a a MASCOT 2542 LI [link](https://www.mascot.no/catalog/medical/2542li/c-24/c-1323/p-174)

The PJ-065A will be the connector used for the charger. The 3 pins and working mode of this connector allow us to have a design where, when the charger is connected, the battery and the circuit are disconnected, and the charger is only powering the battery. In this scenario, when the charger is plugged, the battery is being charged but the circuit won't work. When the charger is not plugged, the battery and the circuit are connected again, and the battery powers the PCB and its components. We want it to work this way.

Thus, we connect the pin 1 of the PJ-065A to the + of the battery and the + of the circuit. Then, the pin 2 is connected to the - of the battery, and finally the pin 3 is connected to the - of the circuit

[image: Circuit with and without charger plugged]

Now, my questions in this design are:

The battery and the circuit are enclosed in a box, and the charger connector we selected (PJ-065A) will be panel mounted to that box, and connected as I explained in the last paragraph to the circuit and the battery. When there is no charger plugged, the battery is powering the circuit, so there is voltage and current running there. In this scenario, and because the connector is exposed to the exterior, there could be some moisture that appears inside the connector, which would cause a short circuit, right?

Question1: is this assumption right? Would this moisture create a short circuit?

Question2: in that case, how shall we prevent this? I know there are some caps we can place outside the connector, but would they be effective in my case?

Question3: is there anything from this design you would change?

Thank you dearly  in advance!

Comment: What voltage and current there needs to be? What charger you intend to use? What battery is it?

Comment: Your circuit looks right but we have no idea whether your jack does what you say it does. Moisture can be a massive problem and that jack does not look in the least bit weatherproof.

Comment: Hello @Justme.


the battery is 2447-3036-20 Ansmann 14,8V 3500mAh [link](https://www.blubattery.com/home/li-ion-battery-packs/2447-3036-20-ansmann-batteria-ricaricabile-li-ion-14-8v-3500mah-type-4s1p-con-ptc-e-safety-board-certificata-un-38-3-e-iec-62133-2-2017.2.7.946.gp.10254.uw). 

 The jack could be a 24V and max current woudl be 2A for this circuit. 

The charger I intend to use is a a MASCOT 2542 LI [link](https://www.mascot.no/catalog/medical/2542li/c-24/c-1323/p-174)

Comment: Hi @Andy-aka, thanks for your answer. I don't understand what you mean by "we have no idea whether your jack does what you say it does" (I am a newbie in this forum, sorry!). Which other information you need in this regard?

You say moisture can be a massive problem and that jack is not weatherproof. I understand you would recommend changing to a weatherproof jack? How can I look for a part like that?

Thanks again.

Comment: @MariaSenye a data sheet link would be needed to determine correct operation and the suitability for the environment.

Comment: @Andy-aka, no problem at all, here is the datasheet: [link](https://www.mouser.es/datasheet/2/670/pj_065a-1778510.pdf)

Comment: You should edit your question to include it please.

Comment: @Andy-aka, also the environment where this goes is inside a house, so I was thinking of a IP54 rating.

Comment: It should be OK for IP54 but, there isn't anything in the DS that explicitly gives me confidence about its suitability.

Comment: @Andy-aka, thanks for the insight. My concern here is, when the charger is unplugged, the battery and PCB are connected and running. Wouldn't a bit of moisture cause a shortcircuit ? This would be fatal

Comment: The build up of moisture would be gradual and, initially, any small currents flowing through the moisture would tend to evaporate it I would have thought.

Comment: Is this a product you intend to sell? A clear problem here is that someone could plug in a different power supply in place of the charger and overcharge the battery with all the dangers that entails. Most well-designed equipment has the charger circuit built in to avoid this problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Andy-aka!

Comment: @Finbarr, yes it is intended to sell, but the charger specifically needs to go outside the box. Like a smartphone would. In this case, I assume all I can do is design my circuit to prevent damage from those events, and place indications for the user so that this does not happen.

Comment: Not a good example, as the devices sold with smartphones are not chargers. They're simply power supplies - the charging circuits are inside the phone.

Comment: @Finbarr I did not know that about the smartphones power supplies, that was interesting.  In any case, the charger needs to be outside the box. As i mentioned earlier, it needs to be a standard Li-ion battery charger. Something like [MASCOT Charger](https://www.mascot.no/catalog/medical/2542li/c-24/c-1323/p-174)

Comment: No, the power supply needs to be outside the box, that can supply power to a charging circuit inside the box. Protection against the wrong supply being plugged in is wise.

Comment: Hi @Finbarr, I think I don't understand you. My requirements are that I need to use a standard Li-Po battery charger like this [Mascot charger](https://www.mascot.no/catalog/medical/2542li/c-24/c-1323/p-174). 
My Li-Po battery is this one: [link](https://www.blubattery.com/home/li-ion-battery-packs/2447-3036-20-ansmann-batteria-ricaricabile-li-ion-14-8v-3500mah-type-4s1p-con-ptc-e-safety-board-certificata-un-38-3-e-iec-62133-2-2017.2.7.946.gp.10254.uw). 

I understand that smartphones do NOT use chargers but power supplies, but in my case I need to use a charger like the one I mentioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Q1)

No, moisture will not cause a "short circuit". Short circuit means usually a direct connection between terminals. Moisture causes corrosion of the contacts and contaminants in the moisture between the contacts make the water to conduct only a small amount of current, further causing electrolysis to corrode the terminals.

For Q2)

It is unknown if the connector is rated to be used in conditions that allow moisture to develop on it. Even if you cap the socket to avoid splashing water, the moisture in warm air can still condensate on cold connector under the cap. To prevent moisture from doing any harm to your connector, buy a connector intended to handle the environment you need.

However, do note that when the charger is unplugged, the connector directly exposes the battery terminals.

Someone might accidentally plug something metallic into the connector contacts and do cause a short circuit. Connecting the battery terminals directly to the connector may not be a great idea. Perhaps you can design in some additional level of protection like a fuse or current limiting or diode or something else.

Comment: Hello @Justme.  Thank you for such a detailed answer, it has helped me a lot. 

I will definitely try to find a connector intended to handle the environment where I will place it. 

Also, thank you for the information about the battery terminals, I had not thought about it previously. 
In my design, I had placed a TVS, to protect it from ESDs, but this would not prevent it from the user unintentionally shortcircuiting the battery terminals. 

From your comments, I will change it to add a fuse:

![image link](https://i.ibb.co/3f4vT5q/Sin-t-tulo.png)